# benfits of using IHttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, ihttphandler

i have to asked that what is the benefits of using interface IHttpHandler in performance point of view.
beacause the same code can be written with using it and without using it?

Answer (score 0):

HTTPHandler is process the incoming request and send response. It is a one of the major component of asp.net. This is used when we need to customize request process / verify the content etc.

The Http Handlers are often useful when the services provided by the high-level page framework abstraction are not required for processing the HTTP request. Common uses of handlers include filters and CGI-like applications, especially those that return binary data.

You also learn about httpmodule for understand the request process by asp.net.

Please check the link

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/549392/WhatplusisplusHttpplusModuleplusandplusHttpplusHan

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/538589/TheplusTruthplusAboutplusHttpHandlersplusandplusWe

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/advantage-of-httphandler-a-certificate-example/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a big hint. In ASP.NET Web Forms, every page implements `IHttpHandler`. You could say that every page *is* an Http Handler.

Answer (score 0):

IHttpHandler provides the ability to implement a very specifc handler for a very specific task.

For example, consider that your page has embedded images that vary depending upon the logged-in user. In such a scenario you have 2 options.

First: In the aspx.cs file (or any relevant code behind) we can identify the exact images that are required for a given user.

Second: Your code behind serves general images on a regular path (even non-existent paths would do) such as /images/homebutton.jpg
You have implemented a HttpHandler that handles any request for the path 'images/homebutton.jpg'. The ProcessRequest method in HttpHandler would identify the logged-in user and return relevant image. Thus main page is agnostic to such a behaviour. This can also save on whole Asp.Net page life-cycle in some scenarios.